# VBS - Multiple arguments

Tags: parameters, vbscript, arguments

I am creating script to pass one or more arguments. The script works fine with one argument but with multiple arguments it fails.

This is the code I have:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
strCommand = Wscript.Arguments(0) & " " & Wscript.Arguments(1) 
WshShell.Run(strCommand)
```

When I run `script.vbs notepad 1` it works, but when I run `script.vbs notepad` it fails.

I searched on the web and tried to moidfy different scripts but none of them worked so I need some help to get me on the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether there is an argument n before you access WSCript.Arguments(n) by looking at WScript.Arguments.Count:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oWAU : Set oWAU = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed
Dim sArg1 : sArg1 = ""
Dim nArg2 : nArg2 = 1
If 1 <= oWAU.Count Then sArg1 = oWAU(0)
If 2 <= oWAU.Count Then nArg2 = CLng(oWAU(1))
WScript.Echo sArg1, nArg2
```

output:

```
args.vbs notepad
notepad 1

args.vbs notepad 4
notepad 4
```

Comment: Now I got:

if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then 
 WScript.Echo "Missing parameters" 
 WScript.Quit 1 
 end if Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
 strCommand = WScript.Arguments(0) 

For i = 2 To WScript.Arguments.Count 
 strCommand = strCommand & " " & WScript.Arguments(i) 
 Next 
 WshShell.Run(strCommand)

When I run cscript script.vbs notepad 1 it gives me SubScript out of range cscript script.vbs notepad works fine. 

Any ideas?